# How can I know in advance if a dock is going to fry a laptop?

Tags: laptop, hp

I have an issue with two docks (same make and model, purchased 1 year appart, non-HP) that fried two HP laptops (same make and model, purchased together) within seconds of being connected.

Both are USB-C certified.

The dock has never fried any other devices prior to the incident. It has been in used for 1+ year on a variety of laptops & Intel NUCs. Some of these laptops were of the previous generation of those that fried.

*How do I know if the dock was not built to the USB-C standard and thus is responsible for frying the laptop or if the laptop was not built to the standard and is responsible for being fried by the dock? Is there a way to know that is non-destructive?*

Comment: perhaps include the make/model of the dock and the HP laptops and someone can research it for you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Have you ever had a HP laptop being fried by a 3rd party dock?](https://superuser.com/questions/1786347/have-you-ever-had-a-hp-laptop-being-fried-by-a-3rd-party-dock)

Comment: What does "fried" mean? Assuming the common definition of "seriously damaged due to discharging more electricity than the device could handle", you would use a volt meter to check the connector. Check for bad grounds, did built up ESD ('static ").

Comment: But also, your should fix your original question rather than creating a new one.

Comment: @JaromandaX: Laptop = HP ProDesk 440 G9 (PN = 6G8U8PA); Dock = DK30CHHPDAU (https://www.startech.com/en-us/universal-laptop-docking-stations/dk30chhpd)

Comment: @Toto, my initial question was closed with a comment it inappropriate. I thought I had to ask the question a different way

Comment: @music3myear By "fried", I meant that two laptops died within seconds of being connected to the dock via its USB-C cable. They are now bricks. 

This happened with 2 different docks: 
One was a one year old dock that has been in use with many different devices including a HP ProBook 430 G8, several Intel NUCs and several ASUS laptops without issue. The dock is still working after it fried the ProBook 440 G9. 
The 2nd dock was a brand new and identical dock purchased with the laptop .  

I am unsure how I can check the voltages on a USB-C connector???

Answer (score 0):

For those that stumble upon this question... A HP specialist technician came onsite a did a series of tests and confirmed the issue.

The HP Probook 440 G9 we purchased had a BIOS version of 01.04.02 .

IF you use a StarTech dock, it WILL kill the motherboard instantly! Note that HP Docks we tested do not have that issue.

After you upgrade the BIOS to 01.07.00 the issue is resolved. The StarTech dock does not kill the laptop anymore.

Note: According to the HP tech, the recommended method to upgrade the BIOS is by using the HP Image Assistant.